# Firebase Notification Sound with DATA Payload

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notifications with the Firebase API from my server and im using data: instead of notification:... When I use notification, the sound works. I just set sound = default and it plays when a notification comes in in the background.

When im using DATA, I still get the message, but no sound is playing when I set sound = default. Will I have to load my sound into the project as mp3? or is there something I have to do in my `FiremaseMessagingService.java` file `onReceive`?

It seems when I use notification in addition. ONY notification is used the data doesn't come through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sound` parameter is a predefined parameter for [Notification payloads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), wherein a Notification Message is (as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)):

> **FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app**. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys.

In other words, the system is the one that handles this automatically. So the behavior you are seeing is the intended behavior.

When using [Data payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) (from the same docs above):

> **Client app is responsible for processing data messages.** Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

You'll have to implement how the details in the payload have to be handled in your `onMessageReceived()` (this is presuming that your app is in foreground, you still have to be aware of how to [handle the messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) depending of your apps status). That includes the `sound` parameter you included.